# How to encrypt all possible strings in a defined character set python?

Tags: python, hash, python-3.x

I am trying to encrypt all possible strings in a defined character set then compare them to a hash given by user input.

This is what I currently have

```
import string
from itertools import product
import crypt

def decrypt():
    hash1 = input("Please enter the hash: ")
    salt = input("Please enter the salt: ")
    charSet = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
    for wordchars in product(charSet, repeat=2):
        hash2 = crypt.METHOD_CRYPT((wordchars), (salt))
        print (hash2)
```

Obviously its not finished yet but I am having trouble encrypting "wordchars"

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What's your "trouble"? Otherwise this isn't a real question.

Comment: the trouble is that it isnt working.

Comment: I meant in what sense is it not working?

Comment: i get this error message `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in decrypt
TypeError: must be string, not tuple
`

Comment: you could [edit] your question and put properly formatted traceback there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`crypt.METHOD_CRYPT` is not callable so the traceback that you provided doesn't correspond to the code in your question. `crypt.METHOD_CRYPT` could be used as the second parameter for [`crypt.crypt()` function](http://docs.python.org/3/library/crypt.html).

Also as [@martineau](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13404223/4279) pointed out `wordchars` is a tuple but you need a string to pass to the `crypt.crypt()` function.

From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/3/library/crypt.html):

> Since a few crypt(3) extensions allow different values, with different
>   sizes in the salt, it is recommended to use the full crypted password
>   as salt when checking for a password.

To find a plain text from a defined character set given its crypted form: salt plus hash, you could:

```
from crypt import crypt
from itertools import product
from string import ascii_letters, digits

def decrypt(crypted, charset=ascii_letters + digits):
    # find hash for all 4-char strings from the charset
    # and compare with the given hash
    for candidate in map(''.join, product(charset, repeat=4)):
        if crypted == crypt(candidate, crypted):
            return candidate
```

#### Example

```
salt, hashed = 'qb', '1Y.qWr.DHs6'
print(decrypt(salt + hashed))
# -> e2e4
assert crypt('e2e4', 'qb') == (salt + hashed)
```

The assert line makes sure that calling `crypt` with the word `e2e4` and the salt `qb` produces `qb1Y.qWr.DHs6` where `qb` is the salt.

Comment: Brilliant, it works thank you very much. Just one other little thing is there a way i can set the "repeat" bit to search a range so it finds hash for character strings between 1-10 for example

Comment: @LWH91: note: for `repeat=10` it would take around a century if `repeat=4` executes in a second. Otherwise it is `itertools.chain.from_iterable(product(charset, repeat=r) for r in range(8))` for 0-7 case.

Comment: Hi again, your solution works fine for the hash you gave but when I try any hash I have it fails to crack it. My hashs are all in this format: aaacT.VSMxhms. Am I right in assuming the salt is "aa" and the hashed string is "acT.VSMxhms". I know that this hash is the word "moth". What hash format was the hash you used in your example and what does the assert line do?

Comment: @LWH91: run `crypt("moth", "aa")` and see what it returns. I've updated the answer to describe the assert.

Comment: what just run it in the terminal? thanks for clearing up the assert line

Comment: @LWH91: no. I meant call the function `crypt` with given parameters and inspect the returned value

Comment: I get a different hash as the return value, it returns 'aaXPqJ3632ccs'. Does this mean I cant use your answer?

Comment: I was running the code for about 8 hours trying to crack the month hash and it didnt manage to do it. How long should I expect it to take?

Comment: @LWH91: it takes 18 minutes on my machine. [Update your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13401296/edit) or [post a new one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with the minimal complete code example that reproduces your problem

Comment: @LWH91: http://sscce.org/ In your case check that it works for `'moth'` and doesn't produce any result for `'month'` in an hour.

Comment: im now running the code on a proper machine not a virtual one like i was doing before and it seems to be running better, just one more thing if the cursor stops flashing does that mean the program has crashed or is it still fine?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm may be better use bcrypt?
https://github.com/fwenzel/python-bcrypt

Answer (score 0):

Below is a simple program that does what you asked:

```
def gen_word(charset, L):
    if L == 1: 
        for char in charset:
            yield char
        raise StopIteration
    for char in charset:
        for word in gen_word(charset, L - 1):
            yield char + word


def encrypt(word):
    '''Your encrypt function, replace with what you wish'''
    return word[::-1]


charset = ['1', '2', '3']


user_word = '12'
user_hash = encrypt(user_word)
max_length = 3


for length in range(1, max_length):
    for word in gen_word(charset, length):
        if encrypt(word) == user_hash:
            print 'Word found: %s' % word
```

Basically, it uses a python generator for generating words from the charset of fixed length. You can replace the encrypt function with whatever you want (in the example is  string reversal used as hash).

Note that with actual modern hashing methods, it'll take forever to decrypt an ordinary password, so I don't think you could actually use this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my completely different answer based on J.F. Sebastian's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13409383/355230) and comment about my previous answer. The most important point being that `crypt.METHOD_CRYPT` is not a callable even though the documentation somewhat confusingly calls a [hashing method](http://docs.python.org/3/library/crypt.html#hashing-methods) as if it were a method function of a module or an instance. It's not -- just think of it as an id or name of one of the various kinds of encryption supported by the `crypt` module.

So the problem with you code is two-fold: One is that you were trying to use `wordchars` as a string, when it actually a tuple produced by `product()` and second, that you're trying to call the id `crypt.METHOD_CRYPT`.

I'm at a bit of a disadvantage answering this because I'm not running Unix, don't have Python v3.3 installed, and don't completely understand what you're trying to accomplish with your code. Given all those caveats, *I think* something like the following which is derived from you code ought to at least run:

```
import string
from itertools import product
import crypt

def decrypt():
    hash1 = input("Please enter the hash: ")
    salt = input("Please enter the salt: ")
    charSet = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
    for wordchars in product(charSet, repeat=2):
        hash2 = crypt.crypt(''.join(wordchars), salt=salt)  # or salt=crypt.METHOD_CRYPT
        print(hash2)
```

Comment: METHOD_CRYPT is not callable. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13409383/4279)