# Python subprocess.Popen usage with a login script fails

Tags: python, shell, authentication, subprocess

I'm trying to do a login script using python that will attempt to login with the shell command `login -q MyUsername` and try multiple passwords. I can already generate the passwords needed but when I try to login using the code below, the `login` command responds that I entered the wrong username although I know I'm writing it correctly. To clarify: I'm creating a script to login using the shell command `login` when I already know the username but not the password. The code below shows what I'm doing (iterating over the passwords).

```
for password in passwordList:
    p = Popen(["login","-q","MyUsername"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE) #The username MyUsername is correct, 100% sure
    print repr(p)

    stdout_value = p.communicate(password)[0] #
    print(str(stdout_value))
    if repr(stdout_value).startswith('Login incorrect\nlogin: '):
        print "ERROR"
    else:
        print "GOOD"
        break
```

If I type in the command `login -q MyUsername` directly into the terminal, I get prompted to write my password whereas using the script returns 'Login Incorrect'. I'm also confused as how `Popen` works and how to write to `stdout`.

Thanks in advance!

(Other question: Is there an easier way to do this? (Attempt to login using multiple passwords) I'm using `login` because it has no lockdown and the user data can't be accessed if it is not by the superuser).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`login` might [read/write directly from/to terminal (tty)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20980965/4279) outside of process' stdin/stdout. You could use `pexpect` instead, read the first reason in its docs [Q: Why not just use a pipe (popen())?](http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/FAQ.html#whynotpipe):

```
import pexpect
output, rc = pexpect.run("login -q MyUsername",
         events={"(?i)password: ": "password"},
         withexitstatus=True)
```

> Is there an easier way to do this?

Read the hashes from /etc/passwd, /etc/shadow and [check those using `crypt.crypt()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13409383/4279). Or use a specialized tool to test for weak passwords such as ["John the Reaper"](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/john.8.html).

Comment: Thank you, pexpect worked for my need. Regarding the second question, I looked at /etc/passwd but the file does not contain any hashes, it contains addresses for applications (I think?) example: _mysql:*:74:74:MySQL Server:/var/empty:/usr/bin/false.

Comment: @romsearcher: do you see any other filename (apart from `/etc/passwd`) in the answer?