# Changing Linux username or password with Python script

Tags: python, linux

I'm writing a Python script that changes the username and password of a Linux account user - it's part of a larger internal web-gui system that queues up password change requests from `apache2` (which can't run as root), and then changes the passwords itself.  The python script itself obviously must run as root in order to change passwords.

The password change function is pretty straightforward:

```
def chpasswd(user, passwd):
    if os.getuid() != 0:
        syslog.syslog("Error: chpasswd.py must be run as root")
        return

    proc = Popen(
        ['/usr/sbin/chpasswd'], 
        stdin = subprocess.PIPE, 
        stdout = subprocess.PIPE, 
        stderr = subprocess.PIPE
    )
    print "Changing: " + user + ':' + passwd
    out, err = proc.communicate(user + ':' + passwd)
    proc.wait()

    print out

    if proc.returncode != 0:
        print "Error: Return code", proc.returncode, ", stderr: ", out, err
        if out:
            syslog.syslog("stdout: " + out)
        if err:
            syslog.syslog("stderr: " + err)
```

The `print` statements are just there for temporary debugging.  This runs fine and doesn't report any errors - there's nothing on `out` or `err`; but for some reason the actual UNIX password simply *isn't changed*.

The script which invokes this function is listening on a locally bound TCP socket.  When it receives a change password request (in the form of `user:password` - later to be encrypted but for now plaintext) it adds it to a queue and then invokes the `chpasswd` function.

So, typical usage would be:

```
# telnet localhost 7001
Trying ::1...
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
jsmith:mynewpassword
```

When the server is running in a bash window (not as a daemon) it prints out:

```
# python chpasswd.py
Starting Password Server
New connection from: 127.0.0.1
Changing: jsmith:mynewpassword
```

The last statement, you can see, is the `print` statement in my `chpasswd` function.

But after doing the above, when I actually try to login as a user using the new password, I get:

```
$ su jsmith
Password: 
su: Authentication failure
```

Is there some obvious thing I'm doing wrong here?  My suspicion was that somehow the connection with `Popen` is not actually closing, or perhaps the single line `user:password` text is not being transmitted.  So I tried doing something like:

```
out, err = proc.communicate(user + ':' + passwd + '\x04')
```

Notice the extra `\x04` character at the end, indicating End Of Transmission.  Adding this in still didn't get it to work however - the password remained unchanged.

I'm running this on Debian Wheezy, in case it makes any difference.

**Update:**

Investigating further, I can see that my `chpasswd` function actually *is* changing the password - if I `cat` the `/etc/shadow` file before and after connecting to my password server, I see there is a different hash.

It's just that when I try to authenticate using the plaintext password, it doesn't work.  Therefore, my suspicion is that somehow, the communication with `Popen` is either adding additional characters, or losing characters somehow.  Of course, since `/etc/shadow` is a hash, I can't figure out exactly what's going on here.

Comment: Have you tried just printing `stdout` to see if everything is going as expected? Also you don't ``PIPE`` stdout or stderr, so that's a problem too for ``communicate``

Comment: Yeah - I just updated to try that.  Nothing is on `out` or `err`

Comment: Just FYI, you don't need to put a big bold notice when you edit your question, we can see a full revision history and things get edited all the time. [Related discussion.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127639/254929)

Comment: Try printing `repr(passwd)`. I don't know how you've setup your server, but it could be there's an erroneous `\r\n` on the end of the password if you aren't stripping the data you get over the socket.

Comment: That was it... so stupid of me, I forget to strip the extra `\r\n` that the telnet client uses.  And to think... I was ready to download the source for `chpasswd.c` and see exactly what's going on...  Anyway, put that as an answer and I'll upvote + accept

Comment: you can check the hash from `/etc/shadow` using [`assert hash_from_shadow == crypt.crypt(plain_text_passwd, hash_from_shadow)`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13409383/4279)

Comment: [`chpasswd(8)` man page says: *"return an error code on exit"*](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/chpasswd.8.html) i.e., `proc.returncode` would be non-zero exit status in your case if there were an error. @Dunes is correct there could be whitespace/non-printable characters in `passwd`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in this particular instance was that telnet adds `"\r\n"` after you press return on entering text. Since your server was not stripping the data of whitespace this was preserved when changing the password.

It is possible to get telnet to not send the carriage return and newline characters by ending a line with the end-of-transmission character (EOT). You can do this by pressing Ctrl-D.

eg

```
$ telnet localhost 7001
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
jsmith:mynewpassword^DChanging: jsmith:mynewpassword
```

Alternatively you can pipe the line into telnet

```
echo -n jsmith:mynewpassword | telnet localhost 7001
```

Obviously, you'll only want to do this for testing or the new password will end up in your shell history. (The `-n` argument suppresses the printing of newline characters by `echo`)

Or you might want to do away with `telnet` altogether and use `netcat` instead.

```
echo -n jsmith:mynewpassword | netcat localhost 7001
```